# Azure published app does not look like debugging app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to do a basic 'cloud project' -> 'Asp.Net Web Application' in VS2017

When I debug the application I get what I expect the 'MVC landing page'.
[image]

Then when I publish i get an Azure landing page, but I was expecting to see my 'MVC landing page'
[image]

It appears to deploy correctly, so I must be doing missing something obvious.

When I publish project from VS2017 I get this:

1>------ Build started: Project: zerocloud, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  zerocloud -> C:\Users\patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\zerocloud\zerocloud\bin\zerocloud.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: zerocloud, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\zerocloud\zerocloud\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://zerocloud20170318070155.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=zerocloud20170318070155 ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (zerocloud20170318070155)
2>Adding ACL's for path (zerocloud20170318070155)
2>Updating file (zerocloud20170318070155\bin\zerocloud.dll).
2>Adding ACL's for path (zerocloud20170318070155)
2>Adding ACL's for path (zerocloud20170318070155)
2>Publish Succeeded.
2>Web App was published successfully http://zerocloud20170318070155.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: It looks like the website is now showing up correctly. Can you share how you got it fixed?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET It is not showing up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website (http://zerocloud20170318070155.azurewebsites.net/) does load correct. Any chance you could be seeing a cached version?

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: stoopid caching :(